# how to changes the values of an array of objects based on another object in laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, algorithm, object

first of all sorry for the poor English.
I want to change the values of an array of objects based on a map array. let me explain it with an example:

```
$map = {
    "name": "esm",
    "type": "noe",
 };

$data = {
    "Sheet1": 
        [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "esm": "omid1",
                "noe": "pdf1",
                "address": "a/b/omid.pdf1"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "esm": "hanie1",
                "noe": "jpg1",
                "address": "a/b/hanie.jpg1"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "esm": "habib1",
                "noe": "doc1",
                "address": "a/b/habib.doc1"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "esm": "sina1",
                "noe": "txt1",
                "address": "a/b/sina.txt1"
            }
        ],
        "Sheet2": 
            [
               {
                    "id": 2,
                    "esm": "omid2",
                    "noe": "pdf2",
                    "address2": "a/b/omid.pdf2"
             },
             {
                 "id": 3,
                 "esm": "hanie2",
                 "noe": "jpg2",
                 "address2": "a/b/hanie.jpg2"
             },
             {
                 "id": 4,
                 "esm": "habib2",
                 "noe": "doc2",
                 "address2": "a/b/habib.doc2"
             },
             {
                 "id": 5,
                 "esm": "sina2",
                 "noe": "txt2",
                 "address2": "a/b/sina.txt2"
            }
        ]
}
```

as you can see the $data has 2 sheets(actually data of an excel file) each has some records and the $map has 2 records that map columns of the sheets to database table columns. I want to create an array of objects with those records of the $data that exists in the $map.
something like this:

```
$result = [
    {
        "name": "omid1",
        "type": "pdf1"
    },
    {
        "name": "hanie1",
        "type": "jpg1"
    },
    {
        "name": "habib1",
        "type": "doc1"
    },
    {
        "name": "sina1",
        "type": "txt1"
    },
    {
        "name": "omid2",
        "type": "pdf2"
    },
    {
        "name": "hanie2",
        "type": "jpg2"
    },
    {
        "name": "habib2",
        "type": "doc2"
    },
    {
        "name": "sina2",
        "type": "txt2"
    },

]
```

I did myself some work on it but I used 3 for loops that is not an appropriate way to handle it. please guide me here :)

this is my attempt but it doesn't works correctly:

```
$uploads = (new FastExcel)->withSheetsNames()->importSheets($request->path);
$sheets = $request->sheets;
$table = $request->table_name;
$maps = $request->map;
foreach ($sheets as $sheet) {
    if(isset($uploads[$sheet])) {
        $records = $uploads[$sheet];
        foreach ($records as $record => $record_value) {
            foreach ($maps as $map => $value) {
                $maps[$map] = $record[$value];
            }
            $records[$record] = $record_value;
        }
    }
}
return $records;
```

for better understanding, I need to import excel files with multi sheets that doesn't match exactly with database table columns so I get a map Array to know use with columns of excel file for each column of database tabale

Comment: Show us your attempt please, it helps us understand your requirement and how to target an answer

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I edited my question and added my attempt and some explanations

Comment: What does that code do incorrectly

Comment: @RiggsFolly   I want to make an array like the $result array provided in the question but I cant!

Comment: Can you show us a `var_export($uploads)` and `var_export($sheets)` and `var_export($table)` and `var_export($maps)`  So we are sure what data you are dealing with

Comment: @RiggsFolly $map is like the map I provided is question and $uploads is like $data provided. and $sheets are actuallt the sheets objects in $data

Comment: Are they JSON like you show?

Answer (score 0):

I used `collect` to convert JSON object into a PHP array.

```
$results = [];

foreach ($sheets as $sheet) {

    $uploads = collect($uploads)->toArray();

    if (isset($uploads[$sheet])) {

        $records = $uploads[$sheet];

        foreach (collect($records)->toArray() as $record) {

            $record = collect($record)->toArray();
            $result = [];

            foreach ($maps as $key => $value) {

                $result[$key] = $record[$value];

            }

            $results[] = $result;
        }
    }
}

return $results;
```